# The background reason of the way of conjugation of Romanian verbs (indicative present tense) for -a ending verbs

Tags: conjugation, romanian

As I have encountered a lot, some Romanian infinitives ending in -a (-a ending group) stick to the "-ez" suffix for indicative present tense conjugation. I know basically and normally we should eliminate last vowel of the verb stem and conjugate using each person's normal suffixes in order to conjugate; but what about those additional suffixes such as "-ez" for -a ending verbs? For example:

> dirija (to direct) : 1-dirijez 2-dirijezi 3-dirijeză 4-dirijăm 5-dirijați 6-dirijeză

or

> salva (to save, preserve, rescue) : 1-salvez 2-salvezi 3-salvează 4-salvăm 5-salvați 6-salvează

But for some others there would be only the verb stem without -ez suffix:

> regreta (to regret): 1-regret 2-regreți 3-regretă 4-regretăm 5-regretați 6-regretă
>
> săruta (to kiss smb.'s cheek): 1- sărut 2-săruți 3-sărută 4-sărutăm 5-sărutați 6-sărută

Does someone know when to add "-ez" suffix and when to not?

Comment: My instinct says that for example -uta all follow the same pattern, but from most infinitives there is not way to predict the pattern reliably.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanian_verbs#Conjugation_groups.  Some of the inconsistency is because many of the words are actually mediaeval or modern loans, they are not just first conjugation verbs inherited from Latin.

Comment: "because many of the words are actually medieval or modern loans"; Then how we would understand that if they are modern loans or medieval?

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for an etymological dictionary of Rumanian.

Comment: You can make some good guesses for some, based on knowledge of French and of patterns of transformations of words inherited directly from Latin into Romanian.  I would say *regreta*, *dirija*, *salva* and *saluta* are obvious.  But not for others.  In any case if you are learning the language it seems easier to just memorise the patterns for the common verbs than to explicitly memorise all that other information in hope of deducing them.

Comment: @A.M.Bittlingmayer: That was my initial suspicion as well, but it just doesn't add up. Even among the given examples, the first three are all neologisms, but obviously belong to different classes. Furthermore, *decreta*, which rhymes with *regreta*, and is also neologic, has *decretez*, whereas the latter has *regret*, as has already been mentioned. To add to the confusion, the native *inset(os)a* has *inset(os)ez*.

Comment: @Lucian My thinking is really that the loans are inconsistent.  But *regreta* is from a verb ending with *-etter*, whereas *decreta* is from a verb ending with *éter*.  So to the second point, it is maybe possible, with some deep knowledge of French and Latin and the loan process, to predict it a bit.

Comment: @A.M.Bittlingmayer: My point was that both loans and native words seem equally “inconsistent”.

Comment: dear @jlawler. No, I don't look for etymology. I just need to find main key to classify them in order to conjugate them easier.

Comment: dear @A. M. Bittlingmayer , I just don't look for etymology. I want to to know that why some of those verbs use "ez" suffix and some do not? Is there any clue?

Comment: Btw, the conjugation for "a dirija" is wrong. 3 and 6 are "dirijează"

Comment: As a Romanian, I've always wondered why Romanian has so many different ways to conjuge verbs but I never understood how you conjuge them, I just know. It's something you just learn by ear I guess. At least for a Romanian. Today I found this site and I found people saying Romanian is easy and I always wondered "How do people even learn Romanian? It's hard". This is one of the reasons I was saying that

Comment: Unfortunately you are looking for an easy rule when there isn't one. If you encounter a new verb and assume a certain conjugation based on its similarity with another verb that you know, my guess is you are more likely to be wrong than to be right. You just have to learn each verb as you see it, just like the irregular English past tense form.

Comment: **Hint :** The afferent nouns are *dirijor, salvator, regret, sarut*.